How to Launch the OpenCamera App from a Web Application on Android Devices?
I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC and need users to open the OpenCamera app instead of the default or built-in camera app on their Android phones when accessing the application via a mobile browser.
My requirements are as follows:
When the user clicks a button on the web page, the device's OpenCamera app should launch.
The user should be able to capture a photo, and the captured photo should be accessible on the web application (e.g., for preview or uploading to the server).
The solution should function directly in the browser without the need for a dedicated Android application.
Is it possible to achieve this functionality using web technologies, and if so, how? Are there any specific configurations or browser limitations I should be aware of? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

You cannot open any app from a browser. You can redirect to a custom scheme or a registered URL in the OS. For example, if Telegram is installed then the tg:// scheme and t.me URL can be handled by the app if the user allows it.

@Parsa99 Currently, I can open the camera app from a webpage when it's loaded in an Android phone browser. I would like to open the OpenCamera app in a similar way.

That's up to the OS, not possible to open a specific app.
